# USB mouse / flash drive don't work in Xubuntu

Tags: 11.10, usb, mouse, xubuntu, usb-drive

I just started now with Xubuntu (11.10) and I don't know why but my mouse works strange. If I try to move my mouse it move in jumps and is not fluid (but if I use my trackpad there aren't any problems). Another really strange thing is if I take off the USB mouse and plug it back in, it doesn't work anymore. Also if I put in a USB flash drive nothing happens. Maybe it's some USB problem or something, but I don't know.

PC: Fujitsu Siemens Amilo.

Answer (score 2):

It could be your USB driver, try uninstalling the driver then reinstall the driver.

Comment: okei, thank for the advice but, How can i install and reistall the drive?